# Curl login not working

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to login to a website in PHP and then store a cookie.However I am not able to get pass the login for some reason.Here is my code so far

First i get the cookie and XSRF-TOKEN .You can consider `$cookie_file_path` to exist but empty

```
$ch               = curl_init("https://ahrefs.com/user/login");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.111 Safari/537.36');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file_path);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file_path );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT , 120);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT , 0);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
```

At this point my cookie file at location  `$cookie_file_path` contain `ahrefs_cookie` and `XSRF-TOKEN`

Now i will send everything via post

```
$ch               = curl_init("https://ahrefs.com/user/login");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.111 Safari/537.36');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8",
    "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate",
    "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8",
    "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    ));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($curl_parameters));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,  $cookie_file_path  );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file_path );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT , 120);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT , 0);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
```

Here are the post data i am sending

```
$curl_parameters = array(
"_token" => $token, # I get the token by just downloading the page with curl and extract the token value.This value is refresh on each post
"email" => xxxxx@gmail.com,
"password" => xxxxx,
"return_to" => "/", #
"remember_me" => 1
);
```

Here is what happen on a successful login

```
POST /user/login HTTP/1.1
Host: ahrefs.com:443
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Cookie: _vwo_uuid_v2=9788FEFE2A8FD2A0894175F5AA899CC9|0edcdb3cdbf14c6dbb9bd958d78f6023; ajs_anonymous_id=%224084d228-28d6-42b7-8129-3faf51983652%22; _vis_opt_s=1%7C; _vis_opt_test_cookie=1; __insp_slim=1453358056412; __insp_wid=88855823; __insp_nv=true; __insp_ref=d; __insp_targlpu=https%3A%2F%2Fahrefs.com%2F; __insp_targlpt=Ahrefs%20SEO%20Tools%3A%20Backlink%20Checker%20%26%20SEO%20Report; km_ai=jRUMYEFwlZb6sEf5ikr900Rt24E%3D; km_uq=; __insp_norec_sess=true; _vwo_uuid=9788FEFE2A8FD2A0894175F5AA899CC9; _vis_opt_exp_12_combi=5; PHPSESSID=mf02jth4fd9nnj626p7i4lqs11; XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6Iit1MWxXUmZPZ0lpQkx3b1pObUtDU2c9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiWGtuSW1sRXRBTWpKY2FIaExBXC8wVzIxZFNOalNWRTI2WXBWdkxLbG5cL3k4VWZqVWllOVJPNHpwZGZcL0xMdFVDOE1WXC8xZUplMkk1SzNqbXFSbXRzZUNnPT0iLCJtYWMiOiIzZDVkMDQzODNiMDAwNzU0NGRkOWM2Y2Y4YmFiNTkxZmFmN2QxNmY2ZWE1ZjkxOTBiOGE0YjhjNTVkNGRkNzE2In0%3D; ahrefs_cookie=eyJpdiI6IkZjb2NzY0U2Q3d0d1wvQ0tKZTBuN1JnPT0iLCJ2YWx1ZSI6IjBEWDBSZ1dFbVNLMlF4RTJhK1lmZ1Q2MFllOG9sUERXTGtPTmFOXC9RQk1YSUdiaG5lVGRmZk1mOG1KUWJMdWxzSEQ1elJBdUVVMk9MalhpcmcrVVcwdz09IiwibWFjIjoiNDM0YzRlM2ZhZWFmMGNiYjA2MDdmMmI2N2E2ZGUyMzRjOGE2OGJkNDFkYWZhODdiYWJjNGRkNGQwNTNjY2E2ZCJ9; _gat=1; ajs_user_id=null; ajs_group_id=null; mp_462869d58108d4904e778d9b2b8fbead_mixpanel=%7B%22distinct_id%22%3A%20%2215262e404c33be-09e7d85a5-424f072e-384000-15262e404c48f2%22%2C%22%24initial_referrer%22%3A%20%22%24direct%22%2C%22%24initial_referring_domain%22%3A%20%22%24direct%22%7D; kvcd=1453360373661; km_vs=1; km_lv=1453360374; wooTracker=RMJYZZqFbCxy; intercom-id=05c5d5fa-ccaa-4744-8c69-4fdb89bfa409; _ga=GA1.2.274586625.1453358055; _gat_elevioTracker=1; _gali=login_form
Origin: https://ahrefs.com
Referer: https://ahrefs.com/user/login
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.111 Safari/537.36
X-DevTools-Emulate-Network-Conditions-Client-Id: 4E0199DA-8C20-44C9-BAAA-5B5AD8C56232

HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 316
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Thu, 21 Jan 2016 07:13:48 GMT
Location: https://ahrefs.com
Server: nginx/1.6.2
Set-Cookie: remember_82e5d2c56bdd0811318f0cf078b78bfc=eyJpdiI6IktHdUtuXC9peTJtTXRnMitmWldnVm5RPT0iLCJ2YWx1ZSI6ImxybTExSHZ5M2NIVXBpXC8wV2lRNmhtS2VKdm02VzhCUWtcL1gyb3FSb2hsVGZvcTAxclwvOUJzcTVjVjd1QjR0OGRpYjZCSEVwdDlCWUVmS05mOFBpRTR2SGNaYWl6Q2NCSWJGRlBwbndHVTgwPSIsIm1hYyI6ImZhMGYzZGM2ZjVkOWI3NDRmYTYzY2Q1OWI5OWRlOWUwZWI4OTU2NzQyYTlmNWM3YjlkZDA1M2FkYzU4OTJiNjEifQ%3D%3D; expires=Tue, 19-Jan-2021 07:13:47 GMT; Max-Age=157679999; path=/; domain=.ahrefs.com; httponly
Set-Cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6IkxVbkVZUVlZTGUyWGE5R0ZFSVwveTd3PT0iLCJ2YWx1ZSI6Ilk3VlRFQ1dvaTFZS1huVFIwZ2k4bXZTSEtRSzFNVlh0QkFkQTNIZnBRc011akJpTlVJblFVVVlGcXBNcExRTThpUmkyTHo5aVpjQzhxeWhROGQ5RzlBPT0iLCJtYWMiOiI5ZTE0ZDUyMjdmMjYwZDY5NmI4YzBiNmQyOTdkNWRhZWNiYTFhYzhmZWMxMzBiZTUwODEyZWJkNDc4ZmZiMGNkIn0%3D; expires=Thu, 21-Jan-2016 09:13:48 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/; domain=.ahrefs.com
Set-Cookie: ahrefs_cookie=eyJpdiI6IjFSU2d2Wm9KRjFycHJkaktUazM3dHc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiXC9xd0I1TWNvMTl4UHN5UnRNUmxYd014dnp6TXNYbnlDQ1hyRTdXTFVUeWZYM1VWWlVHbTNcL0tNa3NlN3lVQmgzTTNrOVdIckVHV0JQNmhielVLMEpmUT09IiwibWFjIjoiMzZkNDU2OWRjMmM4NTMzYjAyNWZhNWFkMDgzYjc4ZWYwOTQ3M2E3Mzg5YzRlNjJhYzk0ZDI5YzE0ZjNkOTIwZiJ9; expires=Mon, 21-Mar-2016 07:13:48 GMT; Max-Age=5184000; path=/; domain=.ahrefs.com; httponly
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.14-0+deb8u1
```

What i am missing here , why i can't login via post ?

**Edit**

If i set a wrong username/password you get the following

```
POST /user/login HTTP/1.1
Host: ahrefs.com:443
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Cookie: ajs_anonymous_id=%22e915c496-7e0b-46fc-8393-ec3c135edeac%22; _vis_opt_s=1%7C; km_ai=8tTicdoOSGYV7D%2F0bUXMtSQ%2BUhc%3D; _vwo_uuid=2E9A1BBEAC643740726E45FEDA088BB0; _vis_opt_exp_12_combi=3; PHPSESSID=mf02jth4fd9nnj626p7i4lqs11; remember_82e5d2c56bdd0811318f0cf078b78bfc=82e5d2c56bdd0811318f0cf078b78bfc=eyJpdiI6IktHdUtuXC9peTJtTXRnMitmWldnVm5RPT0iLCJ2YWx1ZSI6ImxybTExSHZ5M2NIVXBpXC8wV2lRNmhtS2VKdm02VzhCUWtcL1gyb3FSb2hsVGZvcTAxclwvOUJzcTVjVjd1QjR0OGRpYjZCSEVwdDlCWUVmS05mOFBpRTR2SGNaYWl6Q2NCSWJGRlBwbndHVTgwPSIsIm1hYyI6ImZhMGYzZGM2ZjVkOWI3NDRmYTYzY2Q1OWI5OWRlOWUwZWI4OTU2NzQyYTlmNWM3YjlkZDA1M2FkYzU4OTJiNjEifQ%3D%3D; _vwo_uuid_v2=2E9A1BBEAC643740726E45FEDA088BB0|b8caeecf523e81382e01b6691b0f508b; _vis_opt_test_cookie=1; _gat=1; __insp_slim=1453365450618; __insp_wid=88855823; __insp_nv=true; __insp_ref=d; __insp_targlpu=https%3A%2F%2Fahrefs.com%2F; __insp_targlpt=Ahrefs%20SEO%20Tools%3A%20Backlink%20Checker%20%26%20SEO%20Report; km_lv=x; km_uq=; __insp_norec_sess=true; _gat_elevioTracker=1; XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6ImZ3TGkraHJOVmRQMkhKb3NoZHdYNUE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiTThcL2hnY2VGZytGNTZsTXpseWVXb1lvMjVveEpLbFZJUzQ4cHRuNUFWWnpwVVpBSTZKVFdlKzZZN3hLdlpmMHdONGd2cGluTk91RkQ2Q0VJckt1ZWtnPT0iLCJtYWMiOiJjNjE5NWJmOTMyYzI4OWE4ZGFmZThiYjc1MDllYzVkMTBjMDUxNDg4MzQ4YmE5ZjMyOTRhNWM0YTk3ZjM4YmY1In0%3D; ahrefs_cookie=eyJpdiI6IndOUE1BZ1RDOW9VcE1uSU8wRmJwb1E9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiWTZiaTdETG1ZVE8zWjdDNVo5bEc0NmhOU0VjNHFoZTdpTVVNdVhWMEtESUd6ZHQyTjhyY1JXWGdINkFQQmZ6WnlWb2hucUJqSnFoNmZpYjVtZ0txSWc9PSIsIm1hYyI6IjZlNzY5N2VlNzY0NzY1NGU4OWE5YzVlYTE4MmYzYTI4NmEwZDQwNjBjZDBkZGM3MGRjYjRkOGViOGRhYWM5YjYifQ%3D%3D; ajs_user_id=null; ajs_group_id=null; wooTracker=ZRa7vf7TNNp5; mp_462869d58108d4904e778d9b2b8fbead_mixpanel=%7B%22distinct_id%22%3A%20%22152630d4df88d7-087e038c3-424f072e-384000-152630d4df98b5%22%2C%22%24initial_referrer%22%3A%20%22%24direct%22%2C%22%24initial_referring_domain%22%3A%20%22%24direct%22%7D; kvcd=1453365507959; km_vs=1; _ga=GA1.2.959678603.1453360761; intercom-id=08650ca0-7181-47ec-8ecb-0a6b3c045f19; _gali=login_form
Origin: https://ahrefs.com
Referer: https://ahrefs.com/user/login?return_to=%2F
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.111 Safari/537.36

HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 416
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Thu, 21 Jan 2016 08:39:16 GMT
Location: https://ahrefs.com/user/login?return_to=%2F
Server: nginx/1.6.2
Set-Cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6IkRLcHlIS1Z3YTV3RWtrZG1EUklXS1E9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiZU1MaDJYSmp4K2VhaTRoMHp2eklJcWNSQjRONGtNcFA3ek5ubmhpXC9SNUlLVG0yVEZxMGJBUHMxTlBCbW9RM3RweEFGUENzbzFXXC9wRFZtQmlHQlBZdz09IiwibWFjIjoiMDRkMzNkZDQwMGU5MGJkZDJmOTk4MTgxMjA1NWViYzZhMmFhY2QyMjU0NjJjZmE2ODk1YjA3OTI1MmEzOTQ3ZSJ9; expires=Thu, 21-Jan-2016 10:39:16 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/; domain=.ahrefs.com
Set-Cookie: ahrefs_cookie=eyJpdiI6ImZIdEJGUHJSUmo3V2liZjhWaFdwM1E9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiM3pyYkdSMDUxa3VZSXRScXZOb3VTbnBodndkS280SkJ6NzJ0Zm94UHo1ZHF0RVA3MVBKMThyOFJaWTdHTzdRajFycjREWE1rMkhPN1J6Ynl2ajJcL2FBPT0iLCJtYWMiOiIyZmFlMTdiOGFkNjg5YWQ0YTlmMDU3OGZhMDg5ODljNmE5NWIyOWY0NTNhN2FhZDJjYzVjNTViODY1MGYxMGYyIn0%3D; expires=Mon, 21-Mar-2016 08:39:16 GMT; Max-Age=5184000; path=/; domain=.ahrefs.com; httponly
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.14-0+deb8u1
```

Regards

Comment: if you visit the page via browser and input incorrect username or password, does it gives error 403?

Comment: How do you check that you are not logged in?

Comment: @Charlotte Dunois i don't have the remember_ cookie in my cookie file

Comment: @Pooya check edit for wrong login info

Comment: I tried the website but when I put wrong username or password it doesn't give 403